# JavaFX ComboBox check input and change it

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am trying to build a Combobox in JavaFX that should work as followed.
The user should only type numbers in, but the typed numbers have to be formattet.
ex. 111-111-1111.
So if the user types in three numbers a - should be added automatically.
I figured out how to do that.
I blocked everything but numbers with a TexFormatter.

Now the main Part of the problem comes the part after this.
I added a keyevent.key_released place the caret at the end when a key is released.
But if the user is typing too fast it won't work.
Most of the time it works just fine like that, but when is the user every doing something only the way I expect?
I could not find another way to get the actual value of the combobox, because it seems to refresh after hitting enter or so.
Adding the - in the Textformatter resultet in the programm listening to itself and I wasn't able to place the caret at the end position.

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class tester  extends Application{
    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test");
        HBox root = new HBox();

        //
        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {

            @Override
            public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change t) {
                System.out.println(t.getText());
                if (t.isReplaced()) 
                    if(t.getText().matches("[^0-9]")) {
                        t.setText(t.getControlText().substring(t.getRangeStart(), t.getRangeEnd()));}
               
                if (t.isAdded()) {
                    // Add in Formatter //
                    if (t.getControlText().length() == 2 || t.getControlText().length() == 6 && t.getText().matches("[0-9]")){
                        t.setText(t.getText() + "-");
                        combo.getEditor().end();
                    }
                    //
                    
                    if (t.getText().matches("[^0-9]")) {
                            t.setText("");}
                }
                return t;
            }
        };

        combo.setEditable(true);
        combo.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(filter));
        combo.getEditor().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
        combo.getEditor().end();
            });
        root.getChildren().add(combo);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: let the textformatter handle it completely (it can modify everything, caret, selection, text - have a look at the api doc) - don't interfer with an external key handler

Comment: but I found it alway listening to itself and producing the wrong outcome. so when I add it in the formatter and call combo.getEditor().end(); it won't work.

Comment: you _must not_ change the text/field properties directly inside your filter - please read the api doc TextFormatter on how to change text/caret of the _change_ And stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: Thank you. It works: 
t.selectRange(t.getControlNewText().length(), t.getControlNewText().length());